# Linux: issues with rsync -aiv --delete --dry-run source-folder destination-folder

Tags: rsync

so I cloned a folder  into another disk (freshly formatted as ext4) and it completed successfully.

```
rsync -aiv --delete source-folder destination-folder
```

My issue is that if I ran the command above but with --dry-run as an additional parameter, I expect that --no-- files/folders will show up. But all the files and folders shows up again.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I'm running rsync 3.1.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks!

ps. this is not a desktop machine as such there's no "X"

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is to do with the flags/params you are using. `-aiv` try with `-avz` instead.

The ‘i’ parameter is for finer grained control over the information you see, usually you would set a level of info indicated by a number. It’s likely you’re not making any changes or would be should it have been a real run so it’s just listing off it looping over all the files.

Run the avz flags instead in dry mode and that should confirm :)